# Updating "constant" on a NSLayoutConstraint fails with "Cannot assign to 'constant' in 'constraint'"

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I've got the following swift code in my UIView subclass:

```
    for constraint in self.constraints() {
        if (constraint.firstItem as UIView == volumeOverlay && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top) ||
           (constraint.secondItem as UIView == volumeOverlay && constraint.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top) {
            NSLog ("Found constraint. Top is: \(constraint.constant)")
            constraint.constant = 100
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a compile time error:

> ...TrackView.swift:25:37: Cannot assign to 'constant' in 'constraint'

The docs for NSLayoutConstraint say

> Unlike the other properties, the constant may be modified after constraint creation. Setting the constant on an existing constraint performs much better than removing the constraint and adding a new one that's just like the old but for having a new constant.

So what am I doing wrong that I can't update the "constant" variable?

BTW, this is XCode 6.1.1 for iOS8

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got it.  I didn't realize that self.constraints() returns [AnyObject], so i had to convert the "constraint" to a NSLayoutConstraint.

There may be a more elegant way, but here's what I have now:

```
    var y: CGFloat = // do some calculation....
    for constraintObj in self.constraints() {
        if constraintObj.isKindOfClass(NSLayoutConstraint) {
            var constraint = constraintObj as NSLayoutConstraint
            if (constraint.firstItem as UIView == volumeOverlay && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top) ||
               (constraint.secondItem as UIView == volumeOverlay && constraint.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top) {
                constraint.constant = y
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Yay.  it works.

Comment: Have you created the constraint in Interface Builder?  If so the you can create an IBOutlet in your class that allows you to access the appropriate constraint directly - use the assistant editor and ctrl-drag from the appropriate constraint to your .swift file - create the IBOutlet and you can then reference the constraint directly

Comment: Cool!  I didn't realize you could reference constraints directly like that!